# Cloudbees java (non-web) application listening to port?

Tags: cloudbees

I tried to deploy java application on cloudbees, following this doc (http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Java+Container) and this guidelines ([How do you deploy a non-web Java app through CloudBees Jenkins "Deploy Now" feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400163/how-do-you-deploy-a-non-web-java-app-through-cloudbees-jenkins-deploy-now-feat)) and finally managed to run my app on cloudbees, but... I can't connect to it.

In the logs I can see it started just fine, and is listening to port:

```
Starting spray can on 8464
[INFO] [06/11/2014 08:15:33.237] [on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://on-spray-can/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0] Bound to localhost/127.0.0.1:8464
```

My app is on http://spray-can.pawelstawicki.eu.cloudbees.net/, but when I go there, I can see only `502 Bad Gateway`. I also tried http://spray-can.pawelstawicki.eu.cloudbees.net:8464/ but nothing there is even listening on the port.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem here could be that you specified the port when it is injected as an environmental variable ($app_port). Your application should be reachable in http://spray-can.pawelstawicki.eu.cloudbees.net/. Also I think that the output "localhost/127.0.0.1:8464" doesn't sound really good.

Comment: "localhost" - of course! I'm an idiot... Thanks! It works now! (Port is taken from "app.port" property, so it's good)